# using a function to create a button in a second window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am working on a screenshot related python project using tkinter.
In my program I have a second window opened by a button press code below.

```
#Opens the second window
def open_win2():
    global sec_window
    sec_window = Toplevel()
    sec_window.config(height = 1800,width = 1800, bg = "chocolate1")
    sec_picture_box = Label(sec_window,height=800, width=800, image=mainview)
    sec_picture_box.place(x=800, y=100)
```

I want to create a function that when called will create a button in the second window.
Is this remotely possible. I have tried to do the most simple thing I could think of to test if it can be done (Open a lable when called)  the code for the function is which is the command of a button on the root window

```
def create_secondwindow_button():
    screenshot_snap = Label(text = "dog",)
    screenshot_snap.grid(sec_window,column = 1, row = 1)
```

I just get the error message

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Link\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Link/PycharmProjects/Helloworld/main.py", line 67, in create_secondwindow_button
    screenshot_snap.grid(sec_window,column = 1, row = 1)
  File "C:\Users\Link\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2226, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-bd": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If you cant do this do you have to imbed your function within the function that opens the second window?
Thanks a bunch for any help!

Comment: What error exactly do You get, could You edit in the full traceback? Also it would be as simple as defining a function that creates a Button whose parent/master is simply `sec_window`. Also please show Your attempt on creating that button in the other window.

Comment: Hell @Matiiss I have edited in the full error and the code for opening the label in the second window. Thanks for your help once again!

Comment: First of `Label` is not a `Button`, second the widget class takes an argument of master, so basically You don't place master in layout manager methods. In that creating function it should be `Label(sec_window)` and the rest of stuff

Comment: Yeah My goal is to make a button and that is what I was trying to do but I simplified it to the function with a label to try and find out what was going on. I see I am surprised the solution is so easy but I could find it when I searched. Thanks @Matiiss

Answer (score 0):

This is how the function should be:

```py
def create_secondwindow_button():
    screenshot_snap = Label(sec_window, text="dog")
    screenshot_snap.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Also there is no space between kwarg arguments as You can see in my code (per PEP 8 at least).

Also also if You wanted to create a button, it should be:

```py
def create_secondwindow_button():
    screenshot_snap = Button(sec_window, text="dog")
    screenshot_snap.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

And just in case You do, don't do this:

```py
from tkinter import *
```

It is bad practice in general and You should either import what you need:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
```

Or import the module like this

```py
import tkinter
```

or

```py
import tkinter as tk
```

(for example You can use `as` as You need for example You might as well say `as kinter` or sth)

In such case You would need to refer like this:

```py
tk.Button
tk.Label
```

And so on...

Comment: Your right That is how I imported tkinter. It is what I copied of the course I was working through and when people told me not to do it like that I couldn't find all the correct things to import to make it work.  What did you mean by " Also there is no space between kwarg arguments as You can see in my code". Is it because I had an accidental , in mine? @Matiiss

Comment: no, for example You had `column = 1` when as far as I know and per PEP 8 it should have been `column=1`, see there is no space between the operators when it is a keyword argument such as this one. However when it is a variable like `x = 1` there is space, it is a little detail